# BiometricPrompt with Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-biometric-prompt

BiometricPrompt requires either Fragment or FragmentActivity in its constructor. I cannot find out how to use BiometricPrompt from a Composable screen, not in the documentation, not in any tutorial. Has anyone in here dealt with the same problem? Or is there any other way to use biometric authentication in a fully Compose built application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subclass your `MainActivity` from `FragmentActivity`, then in composable get your context:

```
val context = LocalContext.current as FragmentActivity
```

Check out some examples on github: https://github.com/search?l=kotlin&q=BiometricPrompt%20composable&type=Code

Comment: Check this blog post: https://fvilarino.medium.com/adding-a-pin-screen-with-biometric-authentication-in-jetpack-compose-a9bf7bd8acc9

Comment: Doesn't work, I'm getting an exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.testapp.MainActivity cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

Comment: @Hassa As the first sentence says, you need to subclass your `MainActivity` from `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 2):

For those that cannot change their activity base class, there is issuetracker.google.com/issues/178855209 to request for a `biometric-compose` artifact. Unfortunately, as of version `1.2.0-alpha04` no work has been done towards it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was quite simple in the end, but has taken me hours, so here is the answer for anyone struggling with this.

Make sure, that your MainActivity inherits from FragmentActivity(). Then you will be able to cast LocalContext.current to FragmentActivity.

```
val context = LocalContext.current as FragmentActivity
val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(
    context,
    authenticationCallback
)
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `ComponetActivity()` with `FragmentActivity()` then use normal compose view from FragmentActivity()

```
 setContent {
            FingerPrintAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
```

then everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit from AppCompatActivity, which inherits from FragmentActivity, which inherits from ComponentActivity.

Then you can do:

```
inline fun <reified Activity : FragmentActivity> Context.getActivity(): Activity? {
return when (this) {
    is Activity -> this
    else -> {
        var context = this
        while (context is ContextWrapper) {
            context = context.baseContext
                if (context is Activity) return context
            }
            null
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
val activity = LocalContext.current.getActivity<MainActivity>()

val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(
    activity,
    authenticationCallback
)
```