# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.compose.MainActivity cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-biometric-prompt

I am trying to integrate `BiometricPrompt` with `Jetpackcompose`

Here is a snippet of my code which is called on a button click

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val biometricPrompt =BiometricPrompt(context as FragmentActivity,ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {.....
```

The error is `context as FragmentActivity`, not sure how to and what to cast the context as. I tried `Activity`, `ComponentActivity` as well.

As soon as i click the button i get error saying

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.compose.MainActivity cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
```

I tried looking in to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68636261/biometricprompt-with-jetpack-compose) as well but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt#BiometricPrompt(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity,androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback)), `BiometricPrompt` requires a `FragmentActivity`.

> [image]

Check your `MainActivity` class.
It should extend [**`AppCompatActivity`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity) or [**`FragmentActivity`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity) instead of [`ComponentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity).